# Rails Rspec - I can't run any test (Postgres error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, postgresql-9.3

I'v been using Rspec in my project since the beginning. I'm using another computer, then I clone my repository.

When I run: `rspec/spec` or if i run `guard`, I'm getting this error:

```
/home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@vproject/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in 'initialize': FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

Thing is, I never has this problem before. I can run `migrations` without problems. The weird part is: **I configured rspec again. I deleted all files and I re-configured rspec again. If I run `rspec/spec`, everyhing works fin. BUT, if I copy and paste any code into the new project, I'm getting the error again**.

So, for example, I have this file: `spec/controllers/authors_controller_spec.rb` and the file is blank, everything is ok. But, if I type or copy and paste the code from the original project, I'm getting the error.

Any help will be welcome

Comment: It may be due to ruby version and guard version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem sounds like that with a blank file it's not making any DB requests - however as soon as you copy in code, it tries to hit the database and fails.

Double check your test environment database credentials (`#config/database.yml`) and ensure that it is using a username and password that matches the one set up in postgresql on your current machine.

Also, make sure you have run:

> bundle exec rake db:test:prepare

Which will prepare your test database